# In the proof of construction of canonical module

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm reading David Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra, p.539, Theorem 21.15 :

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to understand the underlined statement. Why is it true?

1. My first attempt is,

Question 1. Let $I:=\operatorname{ann}_R(A)$. Can we choose $x \in R$ such that

1. $x$ is a nonzero divisor on $A$ (as in the proof).
2. $\operatorname{codim}((I,x)) = \operatorname{codim}(I)+1$

?

If this question is true, then since $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay,

$$\operatorname{depth}((I,x),R) = \operatorname{codim}((I,x)) = \operatorname{codim}(I)+1=c+1 $$

(I think that I could prove the last equality, and will upload derivation if needed.)

Such $x$ exists? I'm now trying to imitate next argument (His book Theorem 18.7):

[image]

[image]

Seems to that such a trial works?
If not, anyway, is there any other method to prove that such $x$ exists, or that $\operatorname{depth}((I,x))=c+1$?

Anyone helps?

Comment: You've asked about the existence of such $x$. An easy way is to notice that the associated primes of $A$ are all minimal since it's C-M and then use dim A>0.  For another way to show the depth equality, you may refer to lemma 18.3. with the fact that x is a nonzero divisor on A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is related to other question that I asked.

[Existence of a nonzero divisor on some module.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452232/existence-of-a-nonzero-divisor-on-some-module)

There, I asked that

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a local (noetherian) Cohen-Macaulay ring. Let $A$ be a local (noetherian) $R$-algebra that is finitely generated as an $R$-module. And $A$ is also Cohen-Macaulay.
Furthermore, assume that $\operatorname{dim}A >0$.

Then there exists $x \in \mathfrak{m}$ such that

1. $x$ is a nonzero divisor on $A$, i.e., the multiplicaion map $x : A \to A$ is injective map.
2. $x$ is not contained in any minimal prime of $\operatorname{ann}_R(A)$ ?

And the answer is affirmative (proof is given by Jian).

Then we can show that such $x$ satistifes that $\operatorname{codim}((I,x)) = \operatorname{codim}(I)+1$, as I proposed (c.f. the above image, proof of Theorem 18.7) So we are done.